# Hiding android notification bar in actity

Tags: android

I need the code to show and hide the notification bar during an activity.

I try this code:

```
public void goFullscreen() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
}

public void goNonFullscreen() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
}
```

This doesn't work after the content is adding...

Comment: whats the theme you have used for this particular activity in manifest.xml file?

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: remove that line and check.. it works fine for me.

Comment: It don't work, I get: AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the  following line from Android Manifest file.

**android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"**  and check .

Hope it will help you.

This is the code i have used to check it .

```
public class Main extends Activity {


Button magic,button1,button2;
TextView display;
int random;

private Long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
 private Handler handler = new Handler();  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ssss);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            goFullscreen();
        }
    });

 button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            goNonFullscreen();
        }
    });



    }

public void goFullscreen() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
}

public void goNonFullscreen() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: It don't work, I get: AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: oh. i have tested in 4.4 device.. did you added the  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"></uses-permission> permission in manifest file

Comment: even with <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" /> it doesn't work. I'm using Android 4.2.1

Comment: i have tested in 2.3.3 emulator also.

Comment: i have tested without any permission also.. its works well in both device and emulator... i dont know whats the wrong with your side.

Comment: It works on my device too. I will check why it don't work for my project... I'm using Phonegap maybe it's different there...

Comment: let's continue this discussion in a chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22171/discussion-between-charles-and-rajesh